# Two texts superimposed and horizontally aligned

Tags: css

I want to superimposed two texts in css.

I wrote this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container" >
    <span id="w1" >One text</span>
    <span id="w2" >And another superimposed to the first</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container
{
    position:relative;
}
#w1,#w2
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;    
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDkQE/5/)

But I wanted to have the two texts horizontally centered. (Like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/uDkQE/11/) but superimposed).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you want: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDkQE/26/)

First, make it centered by setting `left: 50%;`.
Then, set a width, for example `width: 400px;`
The span has now a offset, let's fix that `margin-left: -200px;` (Use half the width)
Then, at last, center the text inside the span: `text-align: center;`

Comment: Good, but I need to set `width` to the width of the biggest (which I don't have).

Answer (score 0):

try to add this :

```
#w1 { 
padding-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: if this is the way then you can have add
#w1 {
   left: 40px;
  }